# How can I import a xxx.d.ts declairation file in the xxx.tsx class file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writing a react code in Typescript, where I want to put the declaration file seperate with the main class file, so I have a structure like this:

```
src  
├── app  
│   ├── items.tsx  
│   └── items.d.ts
```

When I try to use an interface I defined in the items.d.ts, I got error: `Cannot find name 'IItemProps'`
I cannot import the interface from the items.d.ts and the error is `Module '".../src/app/items"' has no exported member 'IItemProps'`

Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
// items.tsx
import * as React from 'react';

class Items extends React.Component<IItemsProps, IItemsState> implements IItems {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>test</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Items;
```

and

```
// items.d.ts
export interface IItems {
    valid: boolean;
}

export interface IItemsProps {
    validAtInit: boolean;
}

export interface IItemsState {
    values: {[key: string]: any};
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code for both files?

Comment: @kingdaro I have updated the code

Comment: It's very simple. given two modules with the same name but different extensions, the compiler will pick one of them. It has a very specific order of preference. Either put the content in the same file, or name them differently. If this seems strange consider what would happen if you flipped on the `--declaration` emit flag

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks for the reply, this is what I am doing right now (as in the code above), but the TS compiler complains that `Cannot find name 'IItemProps'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward solution is as follows:

Place all of the constructs that comprise the module in a single source file and remove the declaration file.

**Details:**

Remember, that ES Modules are a physical module format, not a logical module format meaning that they correspond directly to URLs. However, the TypeScript compiler does not consider the extension as differentiating them because of its transformation processes.

Given two modules with the same name but different extensions, the compiler will pick one of them. It has a very specific order of precedence.

Either put all the content in the same file, or name them differently.

If this seems strange consider what would happen if you flipped on the `--declaration` emit flag.

`.d.ts`  files are meant to provide type information corresponding to sources that have either have already been transpiled to JavaScript or represent constructs not present as source.

**Note:**
To verify what I've said here, run the compiler with `--traceResolution`. The output will demonstrate exactly what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As in typescript documentation, they layout the file the same way as I described above: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html. Just want to keep the same structure to make things clean

Comment: @YiWang re-read that and you will find it's consistent with what I've said. That very helpful documentation describes the resolution process. It shows how when multiple files with different extensions but otherwise the same names are present, how one is chosen. Specifically, it shows that the source file is given preference, which is the reason that your props interface is not being recognized.